# learnpress curriculum disappeared

Tags: plugins, wordpress-theming, learnpress

When I open a course page the curriculum section is not there anymore.

I disabled some plugins like LifterLMS but nothing happened. Just to mention that first time I worked with courses page I had the curriculum section displayed.
Thank you for your help